# Google Apps Script - Send Email based on value in cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I am new with Google App Scripts and have a spreadsheet with three columns: name, overdue and last contacted: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W04JiFZwpGCD-qddUkNJ9xQ1xiYwZnGhissudF1EvxM/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to send an email reminder to myself which contains the name of anyone with the value overdue in column B.

So far, I have only been able to write a script that sends an email to myself for row 2. I can't figure out how to get the script to loop through the values in column B.

Here is my script:

```
function sendEmail() {
  
  var overdueRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("B2"); 
  var overdueValue = overdueRange.getValue();
  if (overdueValue === "Overdue"){
    var nameRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A2");
    var name = nameRange.getValues();
    var message = 'Reach out to ' + name 
    var subject = 'Reach out to this person.'
    MailApp.sendEmail('myemail@email.com', subject, message);
    }
}

sendEmail()
```

Comment: You are calling `sendEmail` twice like that. careful also with `getValues` which returns a 2d array. Also in this way you are requesting for the active sheet. Instead, specify the sheet name. This won't work as a time driven trigger function if you are planning to use an active sheet like that. After you sort all of this out you can think of how you can create a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Explanation:

Just a few points to make the process clear:

- I assume you are executing  `sendEmail()` from the script editor. In this way, since you also have `sendEmail()` outside of the function, you will end up calling `sendEmail()` twice. Remove the 'global' call of the function and call only `sendEmail()` from the script editor.
- It is not recommended to apply `getRange` on a [spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) object. Define a particular sheet by its name or position. In my example script below, I define the sheet by its name (`Sheet1`). Change that name to your actual case.
- `name` in your code is a 2D array and not a single value. Be careful with this as it is not the correct way to do it.
- In my script below, I define an array of columns `A` and `B`. Names are defined in column `A` and overdue status in column `B`. In this way you can iterate this array, and get single values per iteration by accessing the array itself. I used [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) but feel free to use your own iteration method.

### Solution:

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // change Sheet1 to the name of your sheet
  const data = sh.getRange('A2:B'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  data.forEach(r=>{
     let overdueValue = r[1];  
     if (overdueValue === "Overdue"){
         let name = r[0];
         let message = 'Reach out to ' + name;
         let subject = 'Reach out to this person.'
         MailApp.sendEmail('myemail@email.com', subject, message); 
     }
  });  
}
```

**Sheet that works for the script:**

[image: example]

Comment: This works flawlessly. Apologies for my poor code, I'm used to JS and having some difficulty understanding Google App Scripts. Do you have any recommendations for where I can read up on it?

Comment: @Dpuiatti there is no reason to apologize and ignore vote downs and negative feedback. We are all here to learn. I would recommend you to start [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials) to understand the basics and then you can use other resources such as youtube/stackoverflow etc. I would avoid online blogspots unless the authors are experts on the field.